# Verify gpg signature in Go openpgp

Tags: go, gnupg, openpgp

I'm playing with writing a Go program that downloads and verifies files.
I am hoping to avoid forcing the user to install gnupg (if possible).

Is it possible to verify a downloaded file with a gpg signature (asc file) as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checking-gpg-signature.html) or [here](http://tor.hermetix.org/verifying-signatures.html.en) using Go's openpgp lib or some other Go library?

Any examples demonstrating how to use openpgp to verify a file with an asc signature would be appreciated.

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp

Comment: @saarrrr, I have come across that library already, but it's not obvious to me how to use it in this way. If you could provide an example it would be appreciated. I've tried to clarify my question a little.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/stuart-warren/93750a142d3de4e8fdd2

Comment: @saarrrr That code appears to be encrypting and decrypting stuff. What I am looking for is verifying a downloaded file with an asc signature. There are links to two examples in my question. Take a peek. Basically "gpg --verify package_name.asc" is what I am trying to do, and it looks like I need to add a key (using a fingerprint?) before I can do that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to verify a gpg signature using the following code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        keyRingReader, err := os.Open("signer-pubkey.asc")
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        signature, err := os.Open("signature.asc")
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        verification_target, err := os.Open("mysql-5.7.9-win32.zip")
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        keyring, err := openpgp.ReadArmoredKeyRing(keyRingReader)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Read Armored Key Ring: " + err.Error())
                return
        }
        entity, err := openpgp.CheckArmoredDetachedSignature(keyring, verification_target, signature)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Check Detached Signature: " + err.Error())
                return
        }

        fmt.Println(entity)
}
```

Full code: https://gist.github.com/lsowen/d420a64821414cd2adfb